# What is the most efficient way to call multiple delays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm loading up a webpage and I want each element to load in with the "fade-in" affect. I have the animation working, and I can get one element to do it, however, after my first setTimeout line the rest don't seem to execute.

```
    function runAnimation() {
document.getElementById("object1").style.WebkitAnimation = "fadein 1.7s"; //Animation line 1
setTimeout(donothing(), 5000); //wait 5 seconds
document.getElementById("object2").style.WebkitAnimation = "fadein 1.7s"; //Animation line 2
}
```

My problem is, that second animation line (and anything after it) isn't running. I've tried other styling items on different IDs and it just seems to not execute anything after the setTimeout (is this normal?) So what is the best way to handle multiple delays? As I have a few more objects I need to add in later on.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not work like this. It won't block execution for 5 seconds. It queues the execution of a function for an amount of time, and then immediately moves on to execute the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does nothing is because Javascript doesn't execute `setTimeout` callbacks synchronously. It will execute it asynchronously by adding it to the event loop and then continue on to your next command while it waits to execute your callback. You need to pass your second animation into the timeout, instead of whatever `donothing()` is.

```
  function runAnimation() { 
     // Do your first step
     document.getElementById("object1").style.WebkitAnimation = "fadein 1.7s";

     //Then pass a function to setTimeout that will execute your second step
     setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById("object2").style.WebkitAnimation = "fadein 1.7s"; 
     }, 5000); //wait 5 seconds
}
```

### [MDN - WindowTimers.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

A basic example about how setTimeout uses async callbacks to 'break' the execution flow.

```
   // this first console call will be executed immediately
console.log('I will execute immediately!');

// this function will be scheduled to execute after 2 seconds. 
// Even though its defined second, it will execute last!

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('Ill execute last, event though Im defined second!')
 }, 2000)

// Javascript will just continue forward, making a note that in 
// 2 seconds it has to execute that ^ function. 
// That means this next call will come next despite the 
// previous function not being executed yet.
console.log('Ill come second!');
```

Comment: If I were to need a third animation line, I cannot just do another setTimeout then am I correct? Even if I do it with your methodology that you showed in the second line. Because it will not execute past it, as I understand from your explanation.

Comment: You can add as many `setTimeout` functions as you wish. In simple terms, it will add it to a separate queue outside the normal top-to-bottom execution. In this case, it will wait 5 seconds and execute it. You could add a second one that waits 10 seconds, a third that waits 15, so on and so forth.

Comment: Hmmm...I have added a third animation line in this fashion setTimeout(function(){animation code}, 10000); and it's not executing...should the third setTimeout be elsewhere?

Comment: Feel free to post your full code in a JSBin and I'll take a look at it. I've edited my post to give you a simple example of how the `setTimeout` works asynchronously.

Comment: Ok, so I found the apparent issue. I changed all my animations (which are done in css and called on in Javascript), to alerts and ran them. They are acting exactly as you're describing. However, whenever I do this with animations it doesn't work at all. This must be some sort of limitation or something to that affect. Did you have any experience with this sort of issue?